# How do I make an object follow my house cursor?

Tags: java, graphics, mouselistener

In my game I want to make an object follow my mouse. The mouse coordinates and the those of the rendered map are not equal since mouse coords start at the top-left corner or the screen while the map moves about to simulate movement.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void update() {  //called every game tick, ~60/s
    move();
}   

protected void move() {
    if(Mouse.getB() == 1 && !stray) {
        x += permX = speed * Math.cos(Math.atan2((Mouse.getY() - (Game.getWindowHeight() / 2)), (Mouse.getX() - (Game.getWindowWidth() / 2))));
        y += permY = speed * Math.sin(Math.atan2((Mouse.getY() - (Game.getWindowHeight() / 2)), (Mouse.getX() - (Game.getWindowWidth() / 2))));
    }else {
        stray = true;
        x += permX;
        y += permY;
    }
}
```

With the above code the object reacts to mouse movement based on its position relative to the center of the window and retains the current momentum if the left button is released.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the problem is. Is it not working? If it simply that it is not equal, and is referenced from the middle, just subtract half the width of the window for x and half the length of the window for y.

Comment: Additionally, you constantly do: Mouse.getX() and Mouse.getY(). It is recommended to simply create variables at the beginning of move for Mouse.getX() and Mouse.getY() . And declare it outside of the method. Int getX, getY; in the class. Then in move(),  getX = mouse.getX(); (same with Y). Since WindowHeight and WindowWidth do not change, get those at the top of the class as well.

Comment: @gmanrocks I strongly disagree with your advice. There is no need to create class members for temporary variables of a single function. And window sizes *can* change.

Comment: @Timothy It seems you have working code. What is your question? Do you want to click somewhere and have the object move to that position? Then we need to see more of your code (essentially how you draw your map).

Comment: @NicoSchertler of course their is a need for some of those class variables such as Window size... it's called constants. Additionally, when calling loops that continually create new variables, it is much faster to already have the variable in memory declared at the beginning. Then it is simply a matter of the JVM assigning it during runtime whereas not declaring them as fields results in continually having to declare a new primitive. If you are not familiar with JavaByteCode, there is a "declare" for doubles called dLoad and an assignment called dStore.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Pre-declaration results in dLoad being called once and dStore being called as many times as the loop is called. However, no pre-declaration results in dLoad and dStore being called as many times as the loop runs. Pre declaration reduces the time by approximately half.

Comment: @gmanrocks However, this will put data on the heap instead of the stack, which might make accessing it more costly. For loop variables, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167938) suggests that the compiler is smart enough to factor that out, resulting in an equal number of `load` instructions for both cases. Anyway, this discussion is off-topic for this question. I appreciate you sharing your opinion.